# How to use ImageDataGenerator with nii/NIFTI files using ADNI dataset

Tags: image, keras, computer-vision, nifti, mri

I'm trying to load my data using keras' ImageDataGenerator class, but I am having trouble since the image files are not a standard jpeg/png image file but rather nii.gz files. I found this github repo https://github.com/sremedios/nifti_image_generator/blob/master/utils/nifti_image.py but the dimensions outputted were not matching up and

```
train_generator.next()
```

throws an error of

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (233,189) into shape (197,233,189,1)
```

Comment: When you read in your nifti data, what shape is the data?  `print(data.shape)`

Comment: It is 197x233x189

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Nii file which is standard format for medical images like MR , CT etc. 
You have to use [nibabel](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nibabel_images.html) library to read medical imaging dataset.
Also DLTK library is available from Google for working on medical imaging.